# Php, ZipArchive deletes an empty file?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

here is a little code I wrote:

```
file_put_contents('a.upl', '');
try
{
    $x = new \ZipArchive();
    $x->open('a.upl');
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

it throws a `ZipArchive::open(): Using empty file as ZipArchive is deprecated` message, which is not surprising.
What suprising is, this `a.upl` file gets deleted, which is a little bit strange. Why does it do that? And how to prevent this "x-files, magic"?

Comment: The situation is probably similar to what https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php#117082 explains, I suppose. When you open a new archive and then don't add any file into it, no ZIP file will actually be created. I'm guessing in this situation here the original file probably gets removed as soon as you try to open it, and if you then don't add any file to it, it won't be re-created.

Comment: Perhaps an extra clarification is needed? With `$x->open('a.upl');` you open the `a.upl` as a ZIP archive. It does try to add the empty file to the ZIP archive. For that you need [addFile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php). You don't explicitly state in your question that you understand this, even though you probably do. It's just that the code looks a bit weird.

Comment: Looking at the PHP source it appears that PHP emits the deprecation warning and sets the `ZIP_TRUNCATE` flag, passing this to libzip. The deletion must be happening within libzip, not within PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some poking around in the source, sequence of events is this:

PHP sees the file you gave is empty, the latest version of libzip doesn't allow this, so in preparation for this BC break, PHP sets the `ZIP_TRUNCATE` flag when calling libzip's `zip_open`

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/zip/php_zip.c#L1500

libzip, on receiving this flag, creates a new zip object in memory, linked to this file as the source.

When you then add no files to this and the script exits, libzip calls zip_close, and because the `ZIP_TRUNCATE` flag is set and there are no entries in the zip, the source file is removed.

https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/blob/cf7bf43ba2f85f936705231903aa0d5cfb2fdf11/lib/zip_close.c#L68

You can avoid the x files magic by setting this global flag: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php#ziparchive.constants.afl-create-or-keep-file-for-empty-archive (if your version of libzip is >=1.10)